# How to enumerate a process's handles?

Tags: windows, handle

Is there a way to enumerate a process with a given PID in Windows, and get a list of all his opened handles (locked files, etc.)?

EDIT: I don't care about language. If it's in .NET, I'd be glad, if it's in WinApi (C), it won't hurt. If in something else, I think I can rewrite it :-)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I did a deep googling and found this [article](http://www.codeguru.com/Cpp/W-P/system/processesmodules/article.php/c2827/).
This article gave a link to [download source code](http://www.codeguru.com/code/legacy/system/ntsysteminfo.zip):

I tried method in NtSystemInfoTest.cpp ( downloaded source code ) and it worked superbly.

```
void ListHandles( DWORD processID, LPCTSTR lpFilter )
```

The code has following declaimer:

```
// Written by Zoltan Csizmadia, zoltan_csizmadia@yahoo.com
// For companies(Austin,TX): If you would like to get my resume, send an email.
//
// The source is free, but if you want to use it, mention my name and e-mail address
//
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Superb! It's exactly what I needed (and wasn't unable to google). Thanks. :-)

Comment: Unfortunately, while this works, it still requires calling `NtQuerySystemInformation` which returns *all* handles that then need to be iterated and filtered by required PID. There's no way that I know of to ask the OS for the handles for just one process.

Comment: this does not work when the handle is a pipe. NtQueryObject will hung forever.

Comment: link already died

Answer (score 8):

The command-line '[Handle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/handle)' tool from Sysinternals does this, if you just want a tool.  This won't help you if you're looking for a code solution, though.

Comment: _Handle_'s GUI counterpart [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) can also do this. _Find_ → _Find Handle or DLL_ menu brings up a dialog for this. Search path works only when drive letter is omitted (as mentioned in _Handle_'s documentation).

Answer (score 7):

[Here is an example](http://www.codeguru.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-176997.html) using `ZwQueryProcessInformation` from the DDK. The DDK is now known as the "WDK" and is available with MSDN. If you don't have MSDN, apparantly, you can also get it from [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/peterwie/archive/2006/05/30/611070.aspx).

I haven't tried it, I just googled your question.

```cpp
#include "ntdll.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "ntddk.h"
    
#define DUPLICATE_SAME_ATTRIBUTES 0x00000004
    
#pragma comment(lib,"ntdll.lib")
    
BOOL EnablePrivilege(PCSTR name)
{
    TOKEN_PRIVILEGES priv = {1, {0, 0, SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED}};
    LookupPrivilegeValue(0, name, &priv.Privileges[0].Luid);
    
    HANDLE hToken;
    OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES, &hToken);
    
    AdjustTokenPrivileges(hToken, FALSE, &priv, sizeof priv, 0, 0);
    BOOL rv = GetLastError() == ERROR_SUCCESS;
    
    CloseHandle(hToken);
    return rv;
}
    
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc == 1) return 0;
    
    ULONG pid = strtoul(argv[1], 0, 0);
    EnablePrivilege(SE_DEBUG_NAME);

    HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_DUP_HANDLE, FALSE, pid);

    ULONG n = 0x1000;
    PULONG p = new ULONG[n];

    while (NT::ZwQuerySystemInformation(NT::SystemHandleInformation, p, n * sizeof *p, 0)
        == STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH)
        delete [] p, p = new ULONG[n *= 2];

    NT::PSYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION h = NT::PSYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION(p + 1);

    for (ULONG i = 0; i < *p; i++) {
        if (h[i].ProcessId == pid) {
            HANDLE hObject;
            if (NT::ZwDuplicateObject(hProcess, HANDLE(h[i].Handle), NtCurrentProcess(), &hObject,
                0, 0, DUPLICATE_SAME_ATTRIBUTES)
                != STATUS_SUCCESS) continue;

            NT::OBJECT_BASIC_INFORMATION obi;
            NT::ZwQueryObject(hObject, NT::ObjectBasicInformation, &obi, sizeof obi, &n);

            printf("%p %04hx %6lx %2x %3lx %3ld %4ld ",
                h[i].Object, h[i].Handle, h[i].GrantedAccess,
                int(h[i].Flags), obi.Attributes,
                obi.HandleCount - 1, obi.PointerCount - 2);

            n = obi.TypeInformationLength + 2;
            NT::POBJECT_TYPE_INFORMATION oti = NT::POBJECT_TYPE_INFORMATION(new CHAR[n]);
            NT::ZwQueryObject(hObject, NT::ObjectTypeInformation, oti, n, &n);

            printf("%-14.*ws ", oti[0].Name.Length / 2, oti[0].Name.Buffer);

            n = obi.NameInformationLength == 0
                ? MAX_PATH * sizeof (WCHAR) : obi.NameInformationLength;
    
            NT::POBJECT_NAME_INFORMATION oni = NT::POBJECT_NAME_INFORMATION(new CHAR[n]);
            NTSTATUS rv = NT::ZwQueryObject(hObject, NT::ObjectNameInformation, oni, n, &n);

            if (NT_SUCCESS(rv))
                printf("%.*ws", oni[0].Name.Length / 2, oni[0].Name.Buffer);
    
            printf("\n");
            CloseHandle(hObject);
        }
    }
    delete [] p;
    CloseHandle(hProcess);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well, I googled it too, but I was unable to download DDK for Vista :-( So I thought, that there is some else solution (ProcessExplorer from sysinternals doesnt link ntdll at all)

Comment: ProcessExplorer doesn't link statically to ntdll but it will load it on runtime. You can find it with a depends.

Comment: How do you work around this solution hanging if you're doing ZwQueryObject(.. ObjectNameInformation..) on a pipe with opened with SYNC_READ?

Comment: @nothrow - Every process implicitly links with ntdll, it's part of the Windows loader. This is discussed in the Windows Internals book by Mark Russinovich, see Chapter 3 "Image Loader".