# Monitor files accessed by windows

Tags: c#, .net, winapi

Is there a way to hook into the windows API to view all files accessed by the operating system?

Comment: If you just want to know the all open handles, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/733384/how-to-enumerate-process-handles/750579#750579

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no user-mode API to do this.

If you really need this, you have to write a pseudo-device driver that becomes a part of the I/O stack in the kernel, which is definitely not for the faint of heart. This is how Process Monitor works; it extracts code from its own EXE and dynamically loads it as a device driver (of course, this needs admin permissions).