# Outlook MailItem opened from standalone file, or not?

Tags: outlook, directory, mailitem

I'm developing an Outlook addin in C# and have a problem distinguishing mails opened from a folder (Inbox, Sent etc) from mails opened from a standalone .msg file.

I've tried inspecting the Parent property, but it shows Inbox for both kinds.

Any ideas out there?

/Sam

Answer (score 1):

Looking through the properties, it looks to me that the .EntryID property is blank if the MailItem is opened from the file system, and has a value if the file is opened from within a folder.  This makes sense based on the [help entry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb207146%28office.12%29.aspx) for it; one caveat is that you'd also expect this property to be blank if the message is a new message (i.e. hasn't been saved in a folder, but doesn't exist in the file system either).

From the help concerning blank values:

> Therefore, the EntryID property is not
>   set for an Outlook item until it is
>   saved or sent

You'd want to experiment with it and make sure it definitely behaves correctly before you implemented it :)

Failing all THAT, the next step could be complex; one approach would be to inspect the handles opened by Outlook.  Inspecting them (in a non-priveleged context) via [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) shows that there is a handle for each message; the name of the handle matches the message subject, the path is the file's path.  One solution to enumerate these is in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/733384/how-to-enumerate-process-handles/750579#750579).

HTH,
Geoff

Comment: Thanks! EntryID in combination with Sent is what i was after. A bit nervous about how different mail stores behaves though, but that'll show, I suppose.