# Get Process Status with WinApi in C (Active or Not)

Tags: c, winapi, operating-system

At my operating system course in a project we have to get process status. We are coding with c.

Example output:

```
Process No Process Id Program Name Status Handle Count

1          5780       notepad.exe  ACTIVE 1
```

How can i get status and handle count?

Comment: They just told you to do it without giving you any idea how? Wow! What does that "status" actually mean?

Comment: Given what inputs? What info do you already have about the process?

Comment: Well... i'd say that if a process with that pid exists... it's active.

Comment: we are creating child process in an program and we save their pid and other data in a linked list. When user want to look created child process output will be like example output.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore how can i check that pid exist or not?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: If the process has exited but a handle to it is still open (as is likely in this case), it will have a PID but not be active.

Comment: EnumProcesses should do what you want. (Hasturkun's answer works for the status)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get a process handle using [`OpenProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684320%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with `PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION` as the desired access (or use a handle previously obtained, possibly from [`CreateProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)), then try to get its termination status using [`GetExitCodeProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683189%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). If it returns `STILL_ACTIVE`, the process has not terminated yet, otherwise it has. Don't forget to close the handle using [`CloseHandle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724211%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The first 2 or 3 columns are more or less trivial. Look up msdn for process enumeration.
Handle enumeration is a bit trickier, but also doable, see these:
[link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/733384/how-to-enumerate-process-handles) [link2](http://forum.sysinternals.com/overview-handle-enumeration_topic14546.html)