# How to check if a process communicates with another process?

Tags: c#

Is there any way of checking if a process is communicating with another process?

For example:

CheatEngine and ChessGame from windows.

I need to find a way of checking if cheatengine does something to chessgame.

The given example is a general one , I'm not talking only for cheatengine.

I just have to know the processes which are "connected" to the chessgame.

Comment: Is this related to two processes you wrote/control or just for any inter-process communication? How much, if anything, do you know about the communication between them?

Comment: There are lots of ways two processes could be "connected", and additionally one of the processes might or might not know that the other is "doing something" with it. This question is too general.

Comment: any inter-process communication.The communcation between the two processes is actually a read/write process memory in the second process..This is not a "communication" process but I couldn't find another word to explain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CheatEngine has to get a handle to the ChessGame process to be able to read the memory of ChessGame so one strategy would be to enumerate the handles of all processes to see which processes have a handle to the ChessGame process. Having an open handle to another process does not in itself prove that there is any "communication" taking place but it is a first step.

Enumerating the handles of a process is a pretty low level operation but the Stack Overflow question [How to enumerate process' handles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/733384/how-to-enumerate-process-handles/743178#743178) has some information. You can also use a tool like [Process Hacker](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/) where you can search for handles in the user interface. You simply perform a search for "ChessGame".

Comment: It may only obtain the handle temporarily, inject a DLL of its choosing and then close the handle again, if it has sufficient permissions.