# Get a list of Handles of a process on windows

Tags: c++, c, winapi, process, handler

Is there a way I could retrieve all the file `handlers` belonging to a `process`.
`Process Explorer` utility application is showing all the `handlers` of a `process` when a particular process is selected. But I am not sure , how it does this, thanks for any advice on this

As per process explorer , I have selected the one chrome process and, I am able to see the handlers belonging to that process in the below window.

[image]

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/733384/how-to-enumerate-process-handles

Comment: briefly `ZwQuerySystemInformation(SystemExtendedHandleInformation, pv, cb, &rcb)` do this