# Sysinternals Handle.exe is not detecting process handles that Process explorer can view

Tags: handle, sysinternals, process-explorer

When i run Sysinternal Process Explorer i can see when cheatengine is attached to another process and i cant do the same thing with Handle.exe (Same company command line tool). I have tried each 32 bit and 64 bit versions of Handle.exe . It doesnt show processes , it shows all other handles but processes. Anybody has got an idea about this issue? I just need to view if a process handles another process like Process Explorer does.

Comment: have you ran both elevated?

Comment: @yonisha yes i did  and it didnt worked . Anyway i ve found another way to do it thank you

Comment: Please share :)

Comment: i was trying to finish my anti cheat system with this feature , but i blocked cheat engine with another way , i could not make this technique works properly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to enumerate process' handles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/733384/how-to-enumerate-process-handles)