# Get all Process handles in C#

Tags: c#, winapi

I am writing a small system information application in C#. I want to display (Handle#1 @ 0x12345, ...) all handles my process currently has opened. The Process class offers a method to get the total count of handles but (I think) no way to iterate through them.

```
var process = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
var count = process.HandleCount;
Console.WriteLine($"HandleCount: {count}");
var handle1 = process.Handles[1]; // not available
```

Once I have the process handle count how can I iterate through them?

Comment: You may need to use some WMI classes here!

Comment: Not a full answer but please see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/733384/how-to-enumerate-process-handles